# Add elements for ionic 3 side menu

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, side-menu

In Ionic, I need to add dynamically some elements in the side menu.

When a user log in, I need to show the modules of the user, I get them from an API, but I don't know how to add them to the side menu list.

I have read some docs, but I can't find how to add them, what I do now is to show the modules in the welcome screen but that's not good.

I'm using Ionic 3.15.2

Comment: can you post your code what you tried so far?

Comment: Are the menus common to everyone, but only some users see them?  You could have them all on the side menu and then hide/show based on the user logging in.

Comment: @StevenScott yrs, they are common as you say, I didn't think on that, thank you man

Comment: That is how my side menu works.  I actually set a local storage variable for being logged in, that my application subscribes to (AngularFire2) which will then hide/show the proper side menu options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something related to your requirement; I built a service to get sidemenu options from server after user logs in.

high level steps;

**Login:**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor: 
public events: Events
//after user login publish the event
this.events.publish('userlogin');

app.components.ts:
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor: 
public events: Events;

//subscribe the previous event in constructor and add below in constructor

this.events.subscribe('userlogin',(() => {console.log('Got Events');
this.getDynamicMenuOptions(); // this method gets dynamic side menu options from server }));
```

Comment: If you find my answer worth it then, please upvote the answer as well.